# Which redirection method to use for SEO in my Action Method using ASP.NET MVC? RedirectToAction or RedirectToActionPermanent?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, redirecttoaction

I am creating a web site that will support multiple languages.

I also wanted to localize URL so that it would work like this:

- www.domain.com/en/contact
- www.domain.com/de/kontakt

To achieve that I decided to use different controller for each language.

I also added code that stores visitors prefered language in a cookie.

If same user then visits **www.domain.com** I wanted that the code checks for that cookie and then redirects visitor to index page with appropriate language.

To achieve that I have this code in global.asax for the route

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "en", action = "LanguageRedirect", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

And then in **en** controller there is **LanguageRedirect** action method:

```
    public ActionResult LanguageRedirect()
    {
        string cultureName="";
        HttpCookie cultureCookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];

        if (cultureCookie != null)
        {
            cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
            cultureName = cultureName.Substring(0, 2);
        }
        // Some custom code that checks valid languages
        if (!CultureHelper.isValidCulture(cultureName))
            cultureName = "en";

        return RedirectToAction("Index", cultureName);
    }
```

I am not sure what should be appropriate redirection method regarding SEO? 
Should I just use `RedirectToAction` or should I use `RedirectToActionPermanent`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `RedirectToAction` (302) instead of `RedirectToActionPermanent` (301).

You should 301 redirect basically if the resource has been assigned new URI and the original one is no longer valid.

Refer:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26876/301-redirects-for-regional-variants-of-a-homepage